# Reporting bug to mantis through Squash TM

Tags: java, php, mantis, squash

I configured my bug tracker (mantis) in administration section. Now, I want to add a bug to this bugtracker through squashTM. But I got an error like this:

http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/2739/20130313092653.png

What should I do? When I was trying on different bug tracker (mantis on localhost, not on company server) I got the same error. I suppose that reason is in the mantis core/e_mail_api.php file but don't know what sould I change in this file.
Any ideas? Thanks for your support.

Comment: What version of MantisBT are you using? There is no `$t_status_notification` in the latest version of the core/email_api.php file.

Comment: This is not newest version - it's 1.2.8 mantis version. But now I can see that bug is added to mantis from squash even still I'm getting this error. So know I want to get rid of this only to esthetically purposes.